# Recurring Electronic Personal Payment Service?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer

Is there a service available that allows automated recurring payments for personal transactions?

I have used paypal for one time transfers to friends, but would like to be able to set up a weekly or monthly transfer.

Is there something out there?  Ideally with no transaction fees...

(All transfers are in the US)

Comment: Some banks allow for regular transfers to be set up as automated payments, others allow automated transfers only to utilities or other business accounts. In some cases, there is no fee; in other cases, there is. It might also depend on what kind of checking account you have: a basic no-frills account with minimal minimum balance requirements, or one with more flexibility that requires a minimum balance of (say) $1500 to be maintained to get some services for free.  Why don't you explore _your_ current bank's offerings first?

Answer (score 3):

I use Well Fargo Bill Pay.  Have it set up to transfer a check to my brother every month because we share a family phone plan.  Same goes for my girl friend, we have a gym membership together and she set up Bill Pay to automatically mail a check to me every month.  Works great!  Many other banks have similar programs.  All with no transaction fees and within the US.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that [Venmo](http://venmo.com) works for this. You might want to check it out.